# How to display special character in Span in reactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to print below special characters inside span in ReactJS

```
<span class='child tm'>
    <img src={tick} class='tick'/>A special character !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<>=?@[\]^_`|{}~
</span>
```

Comment: please include your output too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span>Special character! {"!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<>=?@[\\]^_`|{}~"}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try treating them as a string :

```
<span class='child tm'>
    <img src={tick} class='tick'/>{"A special character !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<>=?@[\]^_`|{}~"}
</span>
```

<> are considered as a Tags. Also it is a shorthand syntax of [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below worked fine for me

```
<span class='child tm'>
    <img src={tick} class='tick'/>
    A special character! {"!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<>=?@[\\]^_`|{}~"}
</span>
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).